# error message : io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Tags: python

This is a dice game i've created and i keep receiving the following error message:

```
>   File "/Users/kc/PycharmProjects/programming project/dice game
> script/dice game.py", line 146, in <module>
>     main()   File "/Users/kc/PycharmProjects/programming project/dice game script/dice game.py", line 140, in main
>     leaderboard = get_leaderboard()   File "/Users/kc/PycharmProjects/programming project/dice game script/dice
> game.py", line 112, in get_leaderboard
> return [line.replace('\n', '') for line in l.readlines()] 
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

I don't know why this message comes up and i originally thought it was because "Leaderboard.txt" was saved as w so I changed to an r+ file but the message keeps coming up i think it has got something to do with this:

```
return [line.replace('\n', '') for line in l.readlines()]
```

But I dont know what it is.(I have attached full code below)

full program:

```
import pickle
import random
import time

print("")
print("welcome to the dice game")
print("")

with open('users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    users = pickle.load(f)

def login():

    logged_in = False

    username = input('please enter username: ')

    while not logged_in:

        if username in users:
            password = input("enter password: ")
            if password == users[username]:
                print("access granted")
                logged_in = True

        else:
            print("access denied")

    return logged_in

print("  ")

score_p_one = 0
score_p_two = 0

rounds = 0


def roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    change = 10 if (die1 + die2) % 2 == 0 else -5
    points = die1 + die2 + change
    if die1 == die2:
        points += random.randint(1, 6)
    return points


def game():
    player1_points = 0
    player2_points = 0
    for i in range(1, 6):
        player1_points += roll()
        print(f'After this round user1 you now have: {player1_points} Points')
        time.sleep(1)
        player2_points += roll()
        print(f'After this round user2 you now have: {player2_points} Points')
        time.sleep(1)

    player1_tiebreaker = 0
    player2_tiebreaker = 0
    if player1_points == player2_tiebreaker:
        while player1_tiebreaker == player2_tiebreaker:
            player1_tiebreaker = random.randint(1, 6)
            player2_tiebreaker = random.randint(1, 6)

    player2_win = False
    player1_win = (player1_points + player1_tiebreaker) \

    # > (player2_points, player2_tiebreaker)

    return (player1_points, player1_win), (player2_points, not player2_win)


def add_winner(winner):
    f = open('Winner.txt', 'a')
    with open('Winner.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('{winner[0]},{winner[1]}\n')
```

below is where the error message points to

```
def get_leaderboard():
    f = open('Leaderboard.txt', 'w')
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'w') as l:
        return [line.replace('\n', '') for line in l.readlines()]


def update_leaderboard(leaderboard, winner):
    for idx, item in enumerate(leaderboard):
        if item.split(', ')[1] == winner[1] and int(item.split(', ')[0]) < int(winner[0]):
            leaderboard[idx] = '{}, {}'.format(winner[0], winner[1])
        else:
            pass
    leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)


def save_leaderboard(leaderboard):
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for item in leaderboard:
            f.write(f"{item}\n")


def main():
    user1 = login()
    user2 = login()
    (player1, player1_win), (player2, player2_win) = game()
    if player1_win:
        winner = (player1, user1)
    else:
        winner = (player2, user2)
    print("Well done", winner[1], "you won with", winner[0] ,"Points")
    add_winner(winner)
    leaderboard = get_leaderboard()
    update_leaderboard(leaderboard, winner)
    save_leaderboard(leaderboard)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You opened the file for writing: `open('Leaderboard.txt', 'w')`. You can not _read_ from it. Change `'w'` to `'r'`. Also, remove the line `f = open('Leaderboard.txt', 'w')` - you do not need to open the same file twice. In fact, each of these lines nullifies the file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved: sorry my bad just a simple error of not giving write AND read permissions for Leaderboard.text